# How to draw by hand mathematical figures?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Does there exist a kind of tutorial in order to learn to draw by hand complicated surfaces? For example, the two-sheeted covering of the Klein bottle (drawn by Jean-Pierre Petit in *Le retournement non trivial du tore*, Comptes Rendus Académie des Sciences, tome 293):

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

George K. Francis has a whole book [A Topological Picturebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387345426) 
teaching people how to draw such pictures. Highly recommended.