# Math Diagram Drawing

Tags: soft-question

I recently saw this old sketch of the Gamma function that was done by hand and tools, and I thought that it was really cool. I realized before computer simulations and graphics, if we wanted to visualize a function, we had to accurately draw it ourselves.

It's a question for something very eclectic, but I want to learn about some resources that talk about how to draw diagrams like these, accurately that is. I know there must be a lot of geometric constructions involved. I believe that it must be very similar to engineering diagram constructions. Any good resources?[image: Gamma]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How were 'old-school' mathematics graphics created?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848445/how-were-old-school-mathematics-graphics-created)

Comment: oh! exactly! thanks.